# glückendes amphibisches Leben und einen 90. Geburtstag

Tags: phrase

> Hier geht es um eine Insel im Bayerischen Meer, **glückendes amphibisches Leben und einen 90. Geburtstag.** Und um die Segelyacht Dreamtime.

Is the bolded phrase in nominative case?

https://www.faz.net/aktuell/technik-motor/technik/segelyacht-dreamtime-horizontverschiebung-16216671.html

Comment: Es ist Teil einer Aufzählung, oder? "Hier geht es um A, B und C." "B und C" bilden keine Untereinheit, wenn dann "A, B und C" oder "B" und "C" jeweils eine.

Comment: I do not understand the sentence "wenn dann "A, B und C" oder "B" und "C" jeweils eine"

Comment: Du hast einen Teil des Satzes gefettet und fragst zu diesem etwas in Einzahl. Entweder die Phrase ist länger und beginnt mit "eine Insel" oder "glückendes amph. Leben" und "einen 90. Geburtstag" sind zwei Phrasen, oder? Sprachtheorie und Terminologie sind nicht meine Stärken, aber m.E. müssen doch alle Satzteile dieser Aufzählung im gleichen Fall sein, unabhängig davon, ob sie Teil einer Aufzählung bzw. einer Konjunktion sind. Nebenbei: Zum Nom. fragt man "wer oder was", Akk. "wen oder was". Bsp.: "Hier geht es um wen?" Da Nom. und Akk. mit "was" fragen schmuggelt man eine Person ein. ...

Comment: "Hier geht es um eine Insel, Leben, einen Tag und Peter". - "Hier geht es um wen oder was?" Akkusativ, wie mic richtig bemerkt.

Comment: @userunknown Could you please write in english when commenting.

Comment: Well, you made a part of the sentence bold and asked about it in singular form. Either the phrase is longer and starts with "eine Insel" or "glückendes Leben" and "einen 90. Geburtstag" are two Phrases, aren't they? IMHO all parts of the enumeration have to be in the same case. Btw.: For the nominative, we ask "wer oder was", for akk. "wen oder was". For example "Hier geht es um wen?" Since nom. and akk. ask by "was, we smuggle a person into the sentence "Es geht um eine Insel, Leben, einen Tag und Peter" and now we can ask Es geht um wen oder was?" and see the difference.

Answer (score 4):

No it's accusative as it refers to "es geht um..." which needs accusative.